# Firefox: How to remove easxg.cfg

Tags: windows-10, firefox, firefox-extensions

This I am getting popups, in the lower right corner of the screen, for adds from Firefox.  For example "Best Free anti-virus".  At the bottom of the popup is "via easxg.cfg".

How do I remove this?

I've tried the extensions and this extension is not listed.
I've tried manage extensions, again to no avail.
I've tried manage addons and can't find the addon.

The pop-up is occurring about every 5 minutes.  It was continuous this morning until I reloaded Firefox.

I'm in the process of searching for "easxg.cfg" file on my harddrive.

Comment: 'easxg.cfg' does not appear anywhere on the internet. Are you sure you typed it out correctly?

Comment: Maybe try a full scan with Windows Defender followed by an Offline Scan with Windows Defender

Comment: 'easxg.cfg' is correct, as it popped up again.

Comment: Your Firefox user profile is infected with adware or worse. The file you describe is not legitimate. The notification is very suspicious and most definitely not legitimate

Answer (score 0):

Your Firefox is probably infected.

The first step is to find out if Firefox is really the problem,
so try to use another browser for some time. If the problem doesn't
come up, then the problem is indeed with Firefox.

The simplest solution would be to reinstall Firefox : Save your bookmarks,
uninstall Firefox, cleanup all its folders, then reinstall and import
your bookmarks.

If the problem is still present, you might better address yourself to
the post
[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: Also **export logins**, https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/export-login-data-firefox. if you do not want to hand-enter them all. And, as @John states, the malware could be elsewhere, so perform a *thorough* scan using offline tools, if need be.